# Plotting in GUI of Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, axes

Until now i had only 1 axis in my GUI to I used to just plot directly using plot command. Plus i need to plot these in a loop.

```
for i = 1:length(sig)
    plot(sig(i).time,sig(i).signal,sig(i).time,updated(i).filter,)
    hold on
end
```

Now i have 2 axes in my GUI, how can I make a certain plot appear in 1st axis and another in my 2nd axis

Now for example i need to plot the below in the 2nd axis

```
 for i = 1:length(sig)
        plot(sig(i).time,sig(i).fil,sig(i).time,updated(i).sig,)
        hold on
    end
```

Any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify the axes for `hold` and `plot` functions. Considering you have two axes, `h1` and `h2` inside your figure, you could do the following:

```
hold(h1, 'on')
hold(h2, 'on')
for i = 1:length(sig)
    plot(h1, sig(i).time,sig(i).signal,sig(i).time,updated(i).filter)
    plot(h2, sig(i).time,sig(i).fil,sig(i).time,updated(i).sig)
end
```

Comment: Thanks @erfan , i had no idea i should mention the handles for hold too, can you please tell me how do i link both axes so that i can zoom both together

Comment: `hold` does not accept multiple axes. It is not possible to plot the same curve in both axes with a single use of `plot`. But you can use it for all the axes before entering the loop. Then you should be cautious and include the axes handle for each plot operation in your code. I update my post.

Comment: No, i guess you did not understand my question in the comment, Previous answer was fine. I wanted to link both of the axis to save my zoom, like how we do in subplots.

Comment: Aha! Then you just need to write `linkaxes([h1, h2], 'xy')`, exactly same as how you do it for subplots.